# Prometheus calculate increasing of counter for each data point individually

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have a counter and it increasing regularly.Also I deployed prometheus and that scrapes for every 15 seconds. I  want to see individual changes along the time.

For example:

Prometheus scrapes these data points for a time range:

300 > 350 > 390 > 410

However I want to visualize data changes like that:

... > 50 > 40 > 20

I need a promql query to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus provides [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) function, which **could** be used for this task. For example, `increase(metric[15s])` could return the needed results, e.g. the `metric` increase over the last 15 seconds. But this function has the following issues in Prometheus, which may lead to unexpected results:

- `increase()` in Prometheus may return fractional results when applied to integer counter. See [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746).
- `increase()` in Prometheus misses the counter increase between the last raw sample just before the lookbehind window in square brackets and the first raw sample inside the lookbehind window. This may lead to lower than expected results.
- `increase()` in Prometheus requires at least two raw samples on the specified lookbehind window. Otherwise it returns an empty result.

P.S. There is another Prometheus-like monitoring solution, which provides PromQL-compatible query language and fixes all the issues above in the `increase()` function - [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/). I'm the core developer of VictoriaMetrics.